# Unable to use CompressionCodecFactory to derive compression type

Tags: hadoop, compression

I have compressed the data using gzip compression in hdfs. While reading back from same uri , i am using CompressionCodecFactory , which dynamically finds out the type of compressor being used & retrieve the result. somehow the 
CompressionCodecFactory is not able to read the gzip compression & returns null.

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
CompressionCodecFactory factory = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf);    
CompressionCodec cdc = factory.getCodec(new Path(path));
```

According to documentation it should dynamically fetch type of compressor used & use it somehow returning null to me.

Comment: It's working fine in my environment, ubuntu 14.04 box. Check if path is valid or post more detail.

Comment: Yes in my other setup it is also working. but not in current i m having ubuntu 10